# React JS + PHP(Mysql) = "records.map is not a function";

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

What is my code problem?

My PHP file is returning a json array correctly, the problem is only in the javascript code, javascript is implementing json in the state correctly, only the error when I use the map to display the results.

help

JS file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
export default class Main extends Component{
    state = {
        records : [],
        isLoading : true
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.loading();
    }

    loading = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost/apihunt/carro/read.php");
        const {records} = response.data;   
        this.setState({records, isLoading : false});
        //console.log(this.state.records);
    }

    render(){
        const {records, isLoading} = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {!isLoading ? records.map((car)=>(
                    <div key={car.id}>
                        <p>{car.id}</p>
                        <p>{car.nome}</p>
                        <p>{car.descricao}</p>
                    </div>
                )) 
                    : <p>:(</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

PHP File

```php
<?php
    //Header
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    include '../conf/database.php';
    include '../objects/carro.php';
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $carro = new Carro($db);
    $stmt = $carro->read();
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
    if($num>0){
        $carros_arr=array();
        $carros_arr["records"]=array();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            extract($row);
            $carros_arr["records"][$id] = array(
                "id" => $id,
                "nome" => $nome,
                "descricao" => html_entity_decode($descricao),
                "marca" => $marca,
                "valor" => $valor
            );
        }
        http_response_code(200);
        echo json_encode($carros_arr);
    }else {
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "No products found.")
        );
    }
?>
```

Dump of the php file

```
string(420) "{"records":{"1":{"id":"1","nome":"Ferrari  488","descricao":"uma ferrari n\u00e9, n\u00e3o precisa mais dizer nada","marca":"Ferrari","valor":"1000000"},
"2":{"id":"2","nome":"Uno","descricao":"carro basico","marca":"Fiat","valor":"14000"},
"3":{"id":"3","nome":"Civic","descricao":"carro de luxo","marca":"Honda","valor":"100000"},
"4":{"id":"4","nome":"Hilux","descricao":"carro 4x4 ","marca":"Toyota","valor":"120000"}}}"
```

records.map is not a function;

Comment: If you're sure that the issue is your JS and not your PHP, please remove that tag (and add a dump of the results from the PHP).

Comment: What is the format of your records data? It seems like it's not an array.

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map requires an array, not an object, and therefore the PHP needs to create an indexed array not an associative array.  Most specifically the issue lies here:

```
carros_arr["records"][$id] = [] // defines PHP assoc, becomes JS object
carros_arr["records"][] = [] // defines PHP indexed, becomes JS array
```

You can fix it in two different ways.  You need an indexed array (becomes JSON/JavaScript `array`) in your PHP while you're using an associative array (becomes JSON/JavaScript `object`).  There are 2 ways to fix this:

```
// Before fetch loop define $carros_arr["records"] = [];
$carros_arr["records"][] = [
    "id" => $id,
    "nome" => $nome,
    "descricao" => html_entity_decode($descricao),
    "marca" => $marca,
    "valor" => $valor
];
```

or...

```
$carros_arr["records"] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

If using the one-liner and you need to modify the data:

```
foreach ($carros_arr["records"] as &$record) {
    $record['descricao'] = html_entity_decode($record['descricao']);
}
```

Comment: He could still use an associative array and do: `Object.keys(this.state.records).map((record) => { ... });`

Comment: Good point, hadn't thought of that.  What I consider good practice is structuring the data well server-side, but this is definitely a solution, and to each their own of course